# Authorizing user to firebase doesn’t work

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am creating a basic signup and login page app that goes to the home screen when the user has successfully signed up or logged in. Here is my code:

Here is the where I call the button press function

```
signupButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(signupButtonPressed), for: .touchUpInside)
```

This is the code to create a user and store in the database.

```
@objc func signupButtonPressed() {
    // Check that the text fields aren't empty
    if let username = username.text, let password = password.text, let email = email.text, let country = countryTextField.text {
        // Create a user
        func createUser(withEmail email: String, username: String, password: String, country: String) {

            // Sign up user only if all the text fields are filled
            Auth.auth() .createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) { (result, error) in

                if result != nil {

                    // User found, go to main page
                    let mainPage = MainScreen()
                    self.present(mainPage, animated: true, completion: nil)

                } else {

                    // Error: show error message
                    print("Failed to sign user up with error: ", error!.localizedDescription)
                    return
                }

                guard let userID = result?.user.uid else {return}

                let values = ["email": email, "username": username]

                Database.database().reference().child("Users").child(userID).updateChildValues(values, withCompletionBlock: {(error, ref) in
                    if let error = error {
                        print("Failed to update database values with error: ", error.localizedDescription)
                        return}})
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that, when I press the button, nothing works. Hope someone can help me out, thanks!

Comment: You have a method inside another method, but you don't call func createUser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@objc func signupButtonPressed() {
    if let username = username.text, let password = password.text, let email = email.text, let country = countryTextField.text {
       createUser(withEmail: email, username: username, password: password, country: country)
    }
}


func createUser(withEmail email: String, username: String, password: String, country: String) {
    ...
}
```